# Why does this break in TypeScript 4.8?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

VSCode recently updated to TypeScript 4.8, and since then I've noticed an error in one of my React projects that wasn't there before. What's more, it does not prevent the code from compiling. No error is emitted when building the project. It's difficult to summarize the actual issue, so I'll go ahead and provide some code.

First, some utility types:

```
interface Baz {
  foo: { a: number };
}

const createDefaultExample = <K extends keyof Baz>(x: K): Baz[K] & { x: K; } => {
  return { a: 0, x }; // okay in TS4.7, error in TS4.8
};
```

The function produces an error in 4.8, but not in 4.7:

```
Type '{ a: number; x: K; }' is not assignable to type 'Baz[K] & { x: K; }'.
  Type '{ a: number; x: K; }' is not assignable to type 'Baz[K]'.
    Type '{ a: number; x: K; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: number; }'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'x' does not exist in type '{ a: number; }'.
```

From the error message, I can deduce that the issue comes from expanding the return type of the function. But I'm confused because it seems to do so incorrectly? The second line of the error message seems incorrect, as I wouldn't expect that assignment check to be valid for the return type.

I mentioned TypeScript 4.8 in my opening paragraph, and that is because the only change is that my VSCode also updated today, and one of the changes was to incorporate TypeScript 4.8.2.

This particular function has existed in the code for a few weeks now, and as I said, this has never shown as an error in my code before. And again, `yarn build` produces no errors and compiles the code completely fine.

[TypeScript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwF7IN4ChnIwD2RAXDsnOSAK4C2ARtMgL4DcuLuuCRIAzmGQIoEOJAAiEeDQA2YAKIAPOHQAOslAF5kAHgDSyCEsggAJv2QBrCAE8iMNJgB8ACiXl9ASnLoMAbX0AXWQAMgoPZH02VmQtZxx8ZFEwGigQCipkAAYAGmQlVhiAemLkIis4W2RQZAAVAGUAFgA6AHZ86CgiKBqMxtaADk4gA)

Comment: Things work fine.
(patches)
Weird .. its broke now .. hmm i wonder what it could be..

Comment: How many questions are in this post?  It should be [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/511366).  If there is a primary question where you'd accept the answer to that question alone, then you should make that explicit.  Otherwise you should move each question to its own post.

Comment: "When I attempted to create a simplified example on TypeScript Playground, I noticed that all versions of TypeScript emit the error." Oh, that's a problem, because it means we can't reproduce the issue.  Do you want a version that works in TS4.7 and breaks in TS4.8?  Does [this one](https://tsplay.dev/WP9Oew) work? If so I suggest you replace the code in the question with this one and pare the question down to "why did this break in TS4.8"?

Comment: @jcalz - Fair enough. I included that as additional context as to why I think the issue is my misunderstanding of how something works, as to me that seems like the simplest explanation that has the potential to answer all my questions. I will remove that part from the question.

Also, I'll replace my code with your example code, as it does show the issue better. I'm not sure why mine doesn't, I thought creating explicit types would help with keeping the code simple, but apparently it affects the compiler. Perhaps that is a clue.

Comment: This issue is absent in 4.8.0-dev.20220613 and present in 4.8.0-dev.20220614, so it kind of looks like [ms/TS#49503](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49503) might be the culprit.  I can't be 100% sure without doing more work than I want to put into this.  One might want to open a new properly-submitted [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) about this to find out for certain?  I could write up an answer saying as much if this addresses your question.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - I think you have answered the question. I think I will go ahead submit an issue. Thanks for your help on the matter, it really does seem like a bug in the compiler.

Comment: Furthermore, it seems the issue no longer exists in the nightly build, which is currently on 4.9. So it seems it has been fixed, but VSCode has the bug.

Comment: Oh wait maybe I can find out what fixed it before I answer (and before anyone files a bug)

Comment: So the fix is absent in 4.9.0-dev.20220815 and present in 4.9.0-dev.20220817 so it looks like maybe [ms/TS#50261](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/50261) fixed it?  But I'm not sure, I'd need word back from TS team folks

Comment: Oh darn, I submitted the issue and then saw that you were hoping it could get resolved without one... My bad.

Comment: Well I will write up an answer when I get a chance, but I suppose now we're waiting to see what response [ms/TS#50616](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50616) gets.

Comment: So, is your original bug fixed if you upgrade to nightly?  Looks like they consider the one you filed an actual bug, as well as [ms/TS#50619](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50619) which was filed based on my comment.   Yours is fixed in nightly but mine apparently needs a separate fix.  In both cases it looks like 4.8.3 will probably have the fix, but I want to be sure I describe it right in my answer.  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz - Actually my original example still throws an error with the nightly build. It resolves the indexed type to an intersection type and then says the value is missing properties that are required. I tried adding a link to it in TypeScript Playground but the URL is too long and StackOverflow won't let me use a shortened URL. But you can get it from the edit history of the question and just switch to nightly.

Comment: I don't mean the original *example* here, I mean the bug you had.  The example you put errors in all TS versions past and present and future, right?  So it isn't indicative of something that was working for you before TS4.8.  If you go to whatever code prompted you to write this and re-compile it with nightly, does it succeed or fail?

Comment: Apologies. It appears the error *is* resolved with the nightly build. There clearly must be something different about my example and the actual code, but at least you helped me get to the bottom of it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50616#event-7371977327) in Typescript with the 4.8.2 release. It has since been fixed in the 4.8.3 release.